# Does Google Search Console count two impressions when your site is in two position in the same search result?

Tags: google-search-console, impressions

I'm using the GSC API to query data for my site at a Query & page level.

This means I'm getting impression, clicks, position & ctr for each user query that leads to a url on my site.

However, stuff is really not adding up.

One thought I had was If I want to get the total impressions for my site using the GSC data, I can't simply add this data up. Because (actual anonymized data):

[image]

Suppose, in 1 particular instance - ie. one person entering Query 1, there is  URL 1 on position 1 & Url 2 on position 7. Suppose this hypothetical person clicks on url 2. GSC will record this interaction as:

[image]

Thus, effectively double-counting this single user's impression.

Is this an accurate understanding of how GSC handles cases where multiple urls from the same site show up in the SERP?

Answer (score 2):

Google defines things here:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7042828?hl=en

So you can't really add up rows to get a true total if you are grouping by page.

To add to that, Google does not report all queries. So adding up the rows will typically be a lot less than doing a request for the totals:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553?hl=en